# Finding frequency of each letter of a string and adding it to an array

Tags: c

I have written this program, that opens a text file with something written in it, adding each word of it on a string, finding the frequency of each word, giving the ability to search words starting or ending with a certain letter, capitalising the first and last letter of each word and printing them on another text file like a dictionary.

I only want it to do one more thing and it's done but I cannot figure it how! I want it to find the frequency of each letter of the alphabet, sort them from bigger to smaller and then, when the user inputs a letter, it prints the frequency of it!

I tried something as you can see below but it doesn't seem to work!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define N 100

int main(){
    FILE *fp1, *fp2;
    char buffer[100];
    char *text;
    char *word;
    char *words[N];
    char temp[N];
    char ch1,ch2,ch3;
    char alphabet[26];
    char temp2, temp3;
    int i=0, y=0, c=0;;
    int word_number=0;
    int n=0;
    int *freq;
    int freq1=0;
    int compare=0;
    int last_letter=0;
    int letter_count[256]={0};
    int temp1=0;

    fp1 = fopen("text.txt", "r");
    fp2 = fopen("output.txt", "w");

    if(fp1==NULL){exit(1);
    }

    while(fgets(buffer,100,fp1)!=NULL){
        if(i==0){
            text=(char*)malloc(strlen(buffer)+1);
            strcpy(text, buffer);
        }
        else{
            text=(char*)realloc(text,n+1+strlen(buffer));
            if(text!=NULL){
                strcat(text,buffer);
            }
            else{
                free(text);
            }
        }
        n=n+1+strlen(buffer);
        i++;
    }
    i=0;

    word=strtok(text," \"\n\t\r,.-;!");
    while(word!=NULL){
        strcpy(words[i],word); i++; word_number++;
        printf("%s\n",word);
        word=strtok(NULL," \"\n\t\r,.-;!");
    }

    for(i=0;i<word_number;i++){   //frequency of words
        y=0;
        while(y<word_number){
            compare=strcmp(words[i],words[y]);
            if(compare==0){ freq1++;
            }
            compare=0;
            y++; 
        }
        freq=(int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*word_number);
        strcpy(freq[i],freq1); freq1=0;
    }

    for(i=0;i<word_number;i++){
        printf("The word: %s ,appears %d times!\n", words[i], freq[i]);
    }

    printf("Search all words starting with the letter: ");
    scanf("%c", &ch1);                                   
    for(i=0;i<word_number;i++){
        if(words[i][0]==ch1){
            printf("%s , ", words[i]);
        }

    }

    printf("Search all words ending with the letter: ");
    scanf("%c", &ch2);
    for(i=0;i<word_number;i++){
        last_letter=strlen(words[i]);
        if(words[i][last_letter]==ch2){
            printf("%s , ", words[i]);
        }
        last_letter=0;
    }

    for(c=0;c<26;c++){  //here starts the part i need help with
        if(words[c]>='a' && words[c]<='z'){
            letter_count[words[c]-'a']++;
        }
    }

    for(c=0;c<26;c++){
        alphabet[c]=c+'a';
    }

    for(i=0;i<26;i++){     
        for(y=i+1;y<26;y++){
            if(letter_count[i]>letter_count[y]){
                temp1=letter_count[i];
                letter_count[i]=letter_count[y];
                letter_count[y]=temp;

                temp2=alphabet[i];
                alphabet[i]=alphabet[y];
                alphabet[y]=temp2;
            }
        }
    }

    printf("Type a letter to see its frequency: ");
    scanf("%c", &ch3);
    for(c=0;c<26;c++){
        if(alphabet[c]==ch3){
            temp3=c;
        }
    }
    printf("The letter '%c' appears %d times!", alphabet[temp3], letter_count[temp3]); //the part ends here

    for(i=0; i<word_number-1;i++){   //sorting words alphabetically
        for(y=i+1;y<word_number;y++){
            if(strcmp(words[i], words[y])>0){
                strcpy(temp,words[i]);
                strcpy(words[i],words[y]);
                strcpy(words[y],temp);
            }
        }
    }

    for(i=0;i<word_number;i++){        //printing words to second file
        words[i][0]=toUpper(words[i][0]);
        last_letter=strlen(words[i]); 
        words[i][last_letter]=toUpper(words[i][last_letter]);
        last_letter=0;
        fprintf(fp2,"%s\n", words[i]);
    }

    fclose(fp1);
    fclose(fp2);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: TL;DR this is a lot of code, finding the frequency of letters does not usually require such a large program.

Comment: Loads of `strcpy`s will slow your code down sa well as lots of `for` loops that can actually be put into a pretty big, but more effective one. It would also be better not to write `char` or `int` every time you need to declare some variables. Just say `char a, b, c` then put a backslash and continue declarations on a new line if you want to.

Comment: @ForceBru: Most of your comment is bad advice. If that was meant seriously, you really should get a new coding style-guide.

Comment: I would advise writing some of the functionality in different functions with relevant name, instead of having spaghetti code in main

Comment: @Olaf, actually, I'm not a professional programmer and I'm not even taught C or C++ anywhere. I'm self-taught and unfortunately I don't have _any_ coding style-guide :(

Comment: `strcpy(freq[i],freq1);` this is bad.

Comment: You should consider buying a copy of C Primer Plus, by Steve Prata. It's probably the best resource for self-taught C programmers, and the examples and problems provided at the end of each chapter will definitely help you in the long run.

Answer (score 1):

When doing anything involving counts and "simple" frequency analysis, a histogram-based approach comes to mind.

That looks like much more hassle than it should be. Just replace `str` with a pointer to your string data, and this will take care of counting instances of characters.

You seem to be using a lot of sentinel values, when constants or pre-processor macros would be better. This can be improved.

Finally, consider re-factoring your code into smaller functions like in my example below. It makes it easier to read, and if you post questions on StackOverflow in the future, it lets you separate working code from non-working code, so you can post smaller examples, and get more/better responses.

---

## Code Listing

---

```
/*******************************************************************************
 * Preprocessor directives
 ******************************************************************************/
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
#define ALPHABET_SIZE   (26)

/*******************************************************************************
 * Abstract data types
 ******************************************************************************/
typedef struct histo_t {
    int statistics[ALPHABET_SIZE];  // Bins for storing sums
    int sum;    // In for scaling/normalizing operations
} histo_t;

/*******************************************************************************
 * Function prototypes
 ******************************************************************************/
int CreateHistogram(const char* str, histo_t* pHist);
void PrintHistogram(const histo_t* pHist);

/*******************************************************************************
 * Function definitions
 ******************************************************************************/
/*----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
int main(void)
{
    char str[] = "Hello world. This is a test. ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ. abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz.\n";

    // Create histogram, initialize to zero
    histo_t myHistogram = { 0 };

    // Generate frequency statistics
    if ( CreateHistogram(str, &myHistogram) == 0 )
    {
        printf("Successfully generated histogram.\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Couldn't generate histogram. Aborting.\n");
    }

    // Print out results
    PrintHistogram(&myHistogram);

    return 0;
}

/*----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
int CreateHistogram(const char* str, histo_t* pHist)
{
    if ( !str || !pHist )
    {
        printf("Invalid input.\n");
        return (-1);
    }

    int i;
    for ( i = 0; i < strlen(str); i++ )
    {
        if ( isalpha(str[i]) )
        {
            int idx = tolower(str[i]) - 'a';
            pHist->statistics[idx]++;
        }
        pHist->sum++;
    }

    return 0;
}

/*----------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
void PrintHistogram(const histo_t* pHist)
{
    if ( !pHist )
    {
        printf("Invalid input.\n");
        return;
    }
    if ( pHist->sum == 0 )
    {
        printf("Empty histogram.\n");
    }

    // Print out results
    int i;
    for ( i = 0; i < ALPHABET_SIZE; i++ )
    {
        printf("%c - Count:%d - Frequency:%3.4lf%%\n",
                'a' + i, pHist->statistics[i], 100.0 * (double)pHist->statistics[i] / (double)pHist->sum);
    }
    printf("Total characters:%d\n", pHist->sum);
}
```

---

## Sample Output

---

```
Successfully generated histogram.
a - Count:3 - Frequency:3.5294%
b - Count:2 - Frequency:2.3529%
c - Count:2 - Frequency:2.3529%
d - Count:3 - Frequency:3.5294%
e - Count:4 - Frequency:4.7059%
f - Count:2 - Frequency:2.3529%
g - Count:2 - Frequency:2.3529%
h - Count:4 - Frequency:4.7059%
i - Count:4 - Frequency:4.7059%
j - Count:2 - Frequency:2.3529%
k - Count:2 - Frequency:2.3529%
l - Count:5 - Frequency:5.8824%
m - Count:2 - Frequency:2.3529%
n - Count:2 - Frequency:2.3529%
o - Count:4 - Frequency:4.7059%
p - Count:2 - Frequency:2.3529%
q - Count:2 - Frequency:2.3529%
r - Count:3 - Frequency:3.5294%
s - Count:5 - Frequency:5.8824%
t - Count:5 - Frequency:5.8824%
u - Count:2 - Frequency:2.3529%
v - Count:2 - Frequency:2.3529%
w - Count:3 - Frequency:3.5294%
x - Count:2 - Frequency:2.3529%
y - Count:2 - Frequency:2.3529%
z - Count:2 - Frequency:2.3529%
Total characters:85
```

---

## Edits

As per the comments provided, you should consider adding a second counter inside the `isalpha()` block of code. My check counts the total number of ASCII characters, but not the total number of letters, so the statistics might have a different meaning than what you're after.

Comment: Depending on what you want the frequencies to represent, you might want the `pHist->sum++;` line inside `CreateHistogram()` to be inside the `isalpha()` test (so it's the sum of all alphabetic characters).  Alternatively, you could add a second counter (the existing one for all characters, a second inside the test for the count of all letters).